# Angular 2 app integrate with Java build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Am working on a Angular 2 app (Angular CLI) with Java back end. I do a MVN clean install and this grabs all the file from my angular app and builds it under 'target' folder. How do I tell my app to server from the target folder? at the moment when i run 'npm serve' it executes Dev server.

Comment: do you mean `ng serve --prod` ?

Comment: what do you wanna do exactly? integration with java and angular?

Comment: I want to serve my mvn build target folder, integration with Java is done. I apologize If I wasn't clear

Comment: Are you using SpringBoot

Comment: No am not using SpringBoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For production, surely you want to use something like Apache WebServer or NGINX for hosting your built Angular-App.

For testing the output that was built in `/target` locally, you can navigate to your Angular-project's directory and do:

```
npm install --save-dev http-server
```

then you add to package.json the command

```
"start-production-build": "http-server ./target -c-1 -p 1337",
```

and now you can do

```
npm run start-production-build
```

and open your browser on `localhost:1337`